# Can't do mathematical operations with int from NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults, nsinteger

i have integer data, stored in NSUserDefaults, there is my code:

```
- (IBAction)addButton:(id)sender {
      NSInteger oldValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"myValue"];

    NSString *string1=[addTextField text];
    int add = [string1 floatValue];  
    int new = globalCalories;
    int old=oldValue;

    if(recomended.text==[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", oldValue]){
        **self.day = (int)roundf(old-add);
        dayLeft.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", oldValue-add];
    }**

    else
    {
        self.day=(int)roundf(new-add);
        dayLeft.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", day];
    }
}
```

I copied all of button action code, just in case, but i did mark with bold strings of code, that appear to not work. So, it suppose to do mathematical operations with stored data (oldValue), but when i launch programs, it dosnt, in fact, it does, but instead of valid value program "think" that oldValue is 0 (instead of valid value).

So, when it contain, for example, number 2000, and I launch program and enter in text field 500, it suppose to be 1500 (2000-500), but it shows -500.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855771/cannot-set-nsuserdefaults-field

Answer (score 1):

You can convert recommended.text to integer by using this:

```
int recommendedValue = [recommended.text intValue];
```

then compare the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that == compared the address es of the NSString and not their values (see many SO questions). To compare strings use the [isEqualToString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare%3a) method.

However in this case it would be even better to compare the numbers ie convert recomended.text to the number and use a intValue method on dayLeft.

Comment: i wonder how to convert label.text to that number? Please tell me

Comment: How is recomended.text set and what type is it?

Comment: recomended.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", globalCalories];

Comment: why not store globalCalories in an int in recommended

Comment: What matters is the variable's type not its scope