# How to save User Name and Password in NSUserDefault?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I need to save User Name and Password in NSUserDefault. I am planning to place a round rect button in IB. On pressing of which the User name and Password would be saved in NSUserDefault, so that when user kills the application and tries to login again after some time, they do not need to enter their login details again.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks and best regards,

PC

Comment: Have you considered putting them in the keychain instead?

Comment: Please don't store usernames and passwords into user defaults, take a look at [Keychain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972092/ios-how-to-store-username-password-within-an-app/6972305#6972305).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For Saving Username and Password I will personally suggest to use `Keychain`** as they are more safer than `NSUserDefault` in terms of security since `Keychain` stores data in encrypted form while `NSUserDefault` stores as plain text. If you still want to use `NSUserDefault` Here's the way

**FOR SAVING**

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString
[prefs setObject:txtUsername.text forKey:@"userName"];
[prefs setObject:txtPassword.text forKey:@"password"];

 [prefs synchronize];
```

**FOR RETRIEVING**

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSString
NSString *savedUsername = [prefs stringForKey:@"userName"];
NSString *savedPassword = [prefs stringForKey:@"password"];
```

Answer (score 4):

Do not store plaintext passwords in user defaults, even if they are unimportant.

Use [Keychain Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897). The [Generic Keychain Sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) provides sample KeychainWrapper class, that can be used for reading and writing data into keychain with exactly the same `setObject:forKey:` interface as `NSUserDefaults` uses.

Answer (score 3):

To Save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:_Username forKey:@"Username"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:_password forKey:@"password"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To Read:

```
NSString * _UserName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Username"];
NSString * _password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"password"];
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, I would not store the password in NSUserDefaults. I would rather use the keychain.

This is how you can save the username in NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[standardUserDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"username"];

NSString* username = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"username"];
```

On the other hand, an easy way to use the keychain is by using the [`SSKeychain` class by Sam Soffes](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain); in this case you would just say:

```
NSString* password = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"YOUSERVICENAMEHERE" account:username];

[SSKeychain setPassword:password forService:@"YOUSERVICENAMEHERE" account:username];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store your credentials like this:

```
-(void)saveToUserDefaults:(NSString*)stringUserName pswd:(NSString*)strPassword
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (standardUserDefaults) {
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:stringUserName forKey:@"UserName"];
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:strPassword forKey:@"Password"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    }
}
```

And you can retrive them like this:

```
-(NSArray*)retrieveFromUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (standardUserDefaults) {
        NSString *userName = (NSString*)[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"UserName"];
        NSString *password = (NSString*)[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"Password"];
    }
    NSArray* credentials = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:userName, password, nil];
    return credentials;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cannot set NSUserDefaults field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855771/cannot-set-nsuserdefaults-field/5356954#5356954)

Posted my code from link to stay assured that answer is still useful to community even if the above mentioned post is removed or deleted in future.

**Code:**

You can try this code. I am very sure that it will work for you.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *uid=@"1";
[defaults setObject:uid forKey:@"init_val"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

**For Retrieving Data You Should Use The Following Code :**

```
NSString *initVal=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"init_val"];
```

OR

```
NSString *initVal=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"init_val"];
```

**EDIT:**

If still it gives `nil`, then you can use the following code:

```
NSString *initVal=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"init_val"]];
```

OR

```
NSString *initVal=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"init_val"]];
```

In the above link, you will find my answer and replace "init_val" in my code there with your "username" and "password" as keys

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Good Answers are already given But here is a clean way of **Saving/Loading/Deleting User Credentials** in the **keychain**. Consider this, you can create a separate class and include the following code:

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface KeychainUserPass : NSObject

+ (void)save:(NSString *)service data:(id)data;
+ (id)load:(NSString *)service;
+ (void)delete:(NSString *)service;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "KeychainUserPass.h"

@implementation KeychainUserPass

+ (NSMutableDictionary *)getKeychainQuery:(NSString *)service {

    return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword, (__bridge id)kSecClass,
            service, (__bridge id)kSecAttrService,
            service, (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount,
            (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock, (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible,
            nil];
}

+ (void)save:(NSString *)service data:(id)data {

    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self getKeychainQuery:service];
    SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery);
    [keychainQuery setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:data] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery, NULL);
}

+ (id)load:(NSString *)service {

    id ret = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self getKeychainQuery:service];
    [keychainQuery setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];
    [keychainQuery setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
    CFDataRef keyData = NULL;

    if (SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&keyData) == noErr) {
        @try {
            ret = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:(__bridge NSData *)keyData];
        }
        @catch (NSException *e) {
            NSLog(@"Unarchive of %@ failed: %@", service, e);
        }
        @finally {}
    }
    if (keyData) CFRelease(keyData);
    return ret;
}

+ (void)delete:(NSString *)service {

    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self getKeychainQuery:service];
    SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery);
}


@end
```